# Is the model for small signal right?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

The original circuit is:
[image]

To make the model for small signals, the capacitors behave as short circuits.

[image]

Is the model for small signals right?

Comment: R2 should be in series with the input, it does not go directly to ground. Although R2 is high enough that the error will be small if you delete Rpi altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for high frequencies.

A capacitor behaves as a short circuit only for high frequencies ("high" being defined in relation to the capacitance value and the values of resistors in the circuit).

If you want a small-signal model for low frequencies, you might replace the capacitor with an open circuit instead.

When you learn phasor analysis, you will learn how to find the *reactance* of the capacitor, which will let you make a small-signal model of a circuit with a capacitor that can be used at any frequency.

Comment: But for medium / high frequencies, is the model well done? Does the fact that the capacitors are short circuited also applies to medium frequencies?

Comment: No, it's not a short at medium frequencies. Read my third paragraph.

Comment: And how can I do it for medium frequencies? I am from Physical Engineering and had no discipline of phasor analysis.

Comment: Step 1: Learn phasor analysis. Step 2: Replace the capacitor with an admittance of \$j\omega C\$. Step 3: Analyze the circuit using phasor analysis.